# Checking if file exists in asp.net mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file

I am checking for the existence of a file bu cannot find it, regardless of whether it is there or not

```
if (System.IO.File.Exists("~/files/downloads/" + fileCode + ".pdf"))
            {
                return File("~/files/downloads/" + fileCode, "application/pdf", Server.UrlEncode(fileCode));
            }
            else
            {
                return View("ErrorNotExistsView");
            }
```

How can I amend the code to check for the existence of the file correctly?

Comment: What do you mean "cannot find it"? Does the code enter the "if" part or the "else" part?

Comment: It enters the else part, regardless of the file's existance

Comment: replace "~" with HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("");

Answer (score 53, accepted):

`System.IO.File` will work if you provide an absolute path or a relative path. A relative path will not be relative to the HTML root folder, but the *current working directory*. The current working directory will be a value like `C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express`.

The `~` character at the beginning of the file path is only interpreted as part of the current ASP.NET context, which the `File` methods know nothing about.

The method to help you here is [HttpServerUtility.MapPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Web_HttpServerUtility_MapPath_System_String_)

If you are in a controller method, you can invoke this method on the object `HttpContext.Server`, otherwise (e.g. in a View) you can use `HttpContext.Current.Server`.

```
 var relativePath = "~/files/downloads/" + fileCode + ".pdf";
 var absolutePath = HttpContext.Server.MapPath(relativePath);
 if(System.IO.File.Exists(absolutePath)) ....
```

Comment: I wasn't aware that `File.Exists()` only works for absolute paths, thanks

Comment: msdn for `File.Exists` says: "The path parameter is permitted to specify relative or absolute path information. Relative path information is interpreted as relative to the current working directory. "

Comment: @Sag1v - OK, I've updated my answer to accommodate your feedback.

Comment: I used this in Razor and noted I needed to add `.Current` in the path, i.e. HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(relativePath).

Answer (score 4):

Here's my solution:

```
<span>
@{
    var profileImg = "/Images/" + User.Identity.GetUserId() + ".jpg";
    var absolutePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(profileImg);
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(absolutePath))
    {
        <img alt="image" width="50" height="50" class="img-circle" src="@profileImg" />
    }
    else
    {
        <img alt="image" width="50" height="50" class="img-circle" src="~/Images/profile_small.jpg" />
    }
}
</span>
```

Answer (score 3):

Exists() can return false if app has not sufficient permissions to access the file. So you should grant those to appPool on specific folder and files.

Answer (score 1):

File.Exists() will need the full path.
Try using something like:

`@"C:\users\yourUsername\myDocuments\files\\downloads\" + fileCode + ".pdf"`

instead of:

`"~/files/downloads/" + fileCode + ".pdf"`

Answer (score 0):

```
 @if (Session["staff_no"] != null)
                        {
                            string image = Session["staff_no"].ToString();

                            if (Session["sex"].ToString() == "1")
                            {
                                if (@File.Exists(Server.MapPath("/images/employees/profile_pic/" + image + ".jpg")).ToString() == "True")
                                {
                                    <img id="prof_image2" src="/images/employees/profile_pic/@Url.Content(Session["staff_no"].ToString() + ".jpg")" onerror="this.src = '/images/employees/profile_pic/profile-pic-male.jpg'" class="img-circle" alt="User Image">
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    <img id="prof_image2" src="/images/employees/profile_pic/profile-pic-male.jpg" class="img-circle" alt="User Image">
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (@File.Exists(Server.MapPath("/images/employees/profile_pic/" + image + ".jpg")).ToString() == "True")
                                {
                                    <img id="prof_image2" src="/images/employees/profile_pic/@Url.Content(Session["staff_no"].ToString() + ".jpg")" onerror="this.src = '/images/employees/profile_pic/profile-pic-female.jpg'" class="img-circle" alt="User Image">
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    <img id="prof_image2" src="/images/employees/profile_pic/profile-pic-female.jpg" class="img-circle" alt="User Image">
                                }
                            }
                        }
```